# Suddenly unable to screenshot- Do not have permission to save files in the location where screenshots are stored

Tags: terminal, permission, screen-capture

Recieved the error:
 'Your screenshot could not be saved. You don't have permission to save files in the location where screenshots are stored.' with OS X Yosemite.

I opened terminal and tried directing the screenshots to save on my desktop:

`Brigittes-Air:~ eggsalad$ defaults read com.apple.screencapture location
2017-01-06 03:04:47.765 defaults[17729:1947540] 
The domain/default pair of (com.apple.screencapture, location) does not exist`

So I tried writing and:

`Brigittes-Air:~ eggsalad$ defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Desktop
2017-01-06 03:05:08.652 defaults[17742:1948451] Could not write domain com.apple.screencapture; exiting`

I'm not sure where the screenshots are being stored if the location does not exist. Ideas?

**EDIT**

I ran something else and got a different response, but defaults are still unchanged.

`Brigittes-Air:~ eggsalad$ defaults write com.apple.screencapture location/Users/eggsalad/Desktop killall SystemUIServer`

`2017-01-06 03:22:35.444 defaults[18265:2001767] Unexpected argument SystemUIServer; leaving defaults unchanged.`

**2nd EDIT** 
Result of: 
`ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist`

was:

`ls: /Users/eggsalad/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist: No such file or directory`

Comment: To answer your last question, sounds like they're not currently being saved anywhere. But a Spotlight search for a file called '2017-01-06 03:04:47.765' would tell you for sure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware they're not saving- so that file doesn't exist .

Comment: Can you please run `ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist` and add the result to the question?

Comment: @patrix Tried, added result.

Comment: Hmm, `ls -ld ~/Library/Preferences` as well then, please

Comment: @patrix Response: 

`drwx------+ 196 eggsalad  staff  6664  6 Jan 21:47 /Users/eggsalad/Library/Preferences`

Answer (score 2):

You may have just gotten the commands wrong. Try

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/eggsalad/Desktop
```

make sure to press <kbd>Return</kbd>, then

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

and press <kbd>Return</kbd> again.

Then run

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture location
```

As a last resort, just reset all the settings for your user:

```
 defaults delete com.apple.screencapture
```

Comment: I tried the first command and it unfortunately responded with the same `Could not write domain com.apple.screencapture; exiting`

Comment: I’ve added a reset procedure here @brigitte - instead of writing over a value - just clear all the defaults for this app to get back to the standard settings. Much simpler and shorter command. This helps for other things too like when it copies to the pasteboard instead of writing the file to storage: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328060/